# Need to touch screen twice to get onTouchEvent called

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, layout-inflater, inflate

I am using `onTouchEvent` to capture clicks on buttons. These buttons are in views, inflated in the main view.

My problem is that I have to click twice time on the screen to get my `onTouchEvent` triggered. 
I found a similar topic telling to call `setContentView` after inflating but my app contains many other things so I just cannot call `setContentView` each time I inflate a new view.

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pixeemedical.kneeplus.MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    ... other stuff here 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayout_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My ActivityMain.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMainLayout = findViewById(R.id.rlayout_content);
        mMainLayout.removeAllViews();
        View currentLayoutToAdd = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_to_inflate, mMainLayout, false);
        mMainLayout.addView(currentLayoutToAdd, 0);
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    // called only after second click
                }
        });
    }
}
```